# fork and memory allocations

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, fork

I programming on a parallel implementation of an algorithm, which uses non thread-safe operations. Therefore I use fork() and POSIX-Shared Memory, which works fine. Now the questions. What happens with the dynamicaly allocated memory of the parent, when the child exits? 
The code looks like this

```
int compute(....) {
 //  prepare shared memory 
 pid_t child = fork(); 
 if ( child == 0 ) {
   // process the child code
   int *workspace = malloc(worksize*sizeof(int)); 
   // copy the result to Shared memory 

   free(workspace); 
   exit(0); 
 }
 // do parents work 
 wait(&status); 
 // retrieve results from shared memory 
 return 0; 
 }
```

The problem is that I do not know from where compute is called and which memory is allocated their. The only thing I hope I can grantee is the memory that is allocated by the parent is only used read only in the child. Dynammically allocated memory which is alloced by the child is freed by the child. 
Does this cause a memory leak or not? Valgrind says yes and I dont have an idea to avoid this. Tracking all memory allocations is unfortunately not possible.

Comment: If you allocate before fork, you must free it both in parent and child.

Comment: But if you allocated after fork, you have to free in process that you allocated.

Answer (score 0):

If the code looks exactly as shown, no memory leak is produced. As you say, the child frees all its memory before exit. valgrind may have some problems accounting `fork`ed processes.

Comment: The child only frees the memory which is allocated by it self, not the memory which is previously allocated by the parent process.